# How to add item into popup copy/paste menu on a android selected textview?

Tags: android, textview, contextmenu, copy-paste

please look this screenshot. In normal case, when text be selected, a popup menu opened, but only have cut/paste item. I want to know, how to add item just like this "web search / share" into this popup menu?

What's this popup menu? I had tried to override Activity Context or Option Menu, but it' not. I had also tried to extends TextView and override it's Context menu, but no use, only show a normal dialog context menu, and this cut/paste menu disappered.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Before the api23,I have no ideal too. But now we can get it use `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` with api23.
Include this code in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Install your app, then you can find your app name in the text selection menu.

[image: Sample]

Read the documentation for more information.

Comment: Great! Hope someone can tell us how to customize the popped menu, and use this in TextView, not only EditText.

Comment: I have in Google that whenever I select any text like "https://www.youtube.com/..." It shows YouTube app icon along with options like copy paste. How does it do it?

Comment: any posibility for paste menu ?

Comment: It works fine, but not in all Applications.
In Google keep it doesn't work, as well as in Gmail, WhatsApp and Instagram.
But for example, in Google Chrome it works fine

Comment: @HasanMhdAmin You need [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74417217/15055605) `intent-filter` too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [@jinsihou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6001795/jinsihou)'s answer but as people said it's not working in all apps. After decompiling some apps and checking their `AndroidManifest.xml` I found that you should also add another `intent-filter` too.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="google.com" android:pathPrefix="/test"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I'm not sure what's the significance of `host` or `pathPrefix` so I just entered dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own context menu.
There is a good example of how to do it in [Google Chromium Android sources](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src).

Find the class called `FloatingPastePopupMenu.java` [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/selection/FloatingPastePopupMenu.java) and see how it is used.