# How to show your android app icon along with copy paste menus

Tags: android, gmail, copy-paste, deep-linking, pinterest

On Gmail or Google Application when we select some text which contains an `URL` it shows corresponding app icon along with the copy-paste options.

Refer the image for same :

*(Here pinterest app icon is shown as I select their URL)*

[image]

Similarly I want my Application icon to appear if user selects any text or link which contains `deeplink` `URL` of my `Android` Application. In my case it shows option to open the URL with chrome instead of my installed Android App.
I have searched a lot but didn't find anything relevant on this topic so ultimately thought to post it as question.

How can I achieve this? What changes do I need to do in code for this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can check android app links for this
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

Comment: @AnuragChutani : We do have Applinks/Deeplinks defined but I don't want to open my App on click, rather I want to show App icon along with copy/paste options on selecting any link/text related to my App.

Comment: This is specific to your OS and manufacturer. Unable to see icon on oneplus device.

Can you share device info used in this screenshot?

Comment: same, oneplus 5. Do u have pinterest App installed on my device? or you tried for some other app?

Comment: Just to confirm
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
...................
android:autoVerify="true" and 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

are added in your manifest?

and Link verification is done?

Comment: Yes we have proper implementation done for deeplink handing. I think this (icon with copy paste is different from Applink)

Comment: I have decompiled Pinterest apk and only possible thing found in manifest related to www.pinterest.com and www.pin.it is app links only. If you are able to achieve it. Please post solution here, just curious for implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74417217/15055605).